# Efficiently getting an article from a Wiki dump by title

Tags: mysql, wiki, dump

Going through the xml file obviously takes a lot of time.

Tried importing it into a MySQL database, but unfortunately querying it also takes more than 10 seconds for retrieving a single article by title (i.e. WHERE title = 'X').

```
CREATE TABLE article (
  articleid INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  content LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (articleid),
  FULLTEXT KEY title (title)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


mysql> SELECT title FROM article WHERE title = 'Main Page';
+-----------+
| title     |
+-----------+
| Main Page |
+-----------+
1 row in set (20.61 sec)
```

Although it's probably obvious, I should note that the dump is pretty big, about 2GB or so.

Any ideas on how I could do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a FULLTEXT index for a search that doesn't require one. Create a normal index on `title` and you'll get much faster results.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, I did, but I don't know, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've updated my question and added the table structure and a query for example.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.